# Getting forward slash before the URL Using the preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

Getting forward slash before the URL Using the preg_replace

```
$contentss = file_get_contents("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?LinkName=pubmed_pubmed&from_uid=18032633" ); 
preg_match('/<div class="rprt">(.*)<\/div>/',$contentss,$matches);

$patterns = '/pubmed/';

$replacements = 'http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed';

$string = '<a href="pubmed/"></a>';

$getreplacements = ( preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $matches));

echo $getreplacements[0];
```

Out put is displaying like **/http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed** in anchor tag href. I want remove that forward slash before http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed.

Please help out of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `ltrim($getreplacements[0], '/');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$patterns = '/pubmed/';` with `$patterns = '/\/pubmed/';`

Comment: yes i did..but throwing function error...you can check that code in your side..please

Comment: hey i got that...i think you modified the answer now.. it is working fine.. Thank you so much Rohit..

Answer (score 0):

It's simple change your REGEX to

```
$patterns = '/\/pubmed/';
```

And in that way it will change `/pubmed` to your url `http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed`

`/` needs to be escaped in **regex**.

I've tested it and it's working.

Comment: Ya samething said Rohit below..That is working.. and thanks for the reply

Comment: You've written it doesn't work so I've checked it and it worked for me. :)